# Invoking a complex find command from Python using subprocess

Tags: bash, shell-script, python

I'm currently making use of a complex find command to delete files that has a specific MIME type.

```
find -type f -exec bash -c '
  for f; do
    file=$(file -- "$f")
    if [[ $file =~ ^$f:\ "C source" ]]; then
      echo rm -- "$f"
    fi
  done
' bash {} +
```

I wanted to make use of python to run the following command as per my requirements. When I try to use subprocess to invoke the command I do not any output. I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it as I'm new to linux. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from subprocess import call
call('''
find -type f -exec bash -c '
  for f; do
    file=$(file -- "$f")
    if [[ $file =~ ^$f:\ "ASCII text" ]]; then
      echo rm -- "$f"
    fi
  done
' bash {} +

''', shell=True)
```

I currently have a set of files in my directory and I'm running this python script from the same directory. I'm expecting a set of filenames as an output since there are few matches for 'C source'

Answer (score 0):

The function [subprocess.call()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) returns a **returncode** (zero is success, non zero means some error occured).

If you want the command output use the function [subprocess.check_output(...)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

PS: haven't you considered write it all in Python? The std module [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is great for that.

Comment: Thanks. I tried subprocess.check_output() too but I don't get the output. For some reason the find command does not execute . Not sure if this is a right way to invoke a shell command from python

Comment: @dmorgan The reason probably is that you don't have `\` at the end of each line of your shell multiline command.

```python
from subprocess import call
call('''
find -type f -exec bash -c ' \
  for f; do \
    file=$(file -- "$f") \
    if [[ $file =~ ^$f:\ "ASCII text" ]]; then \
      echo rm -- "$f" \
    fi \
  done \
' bash {} +
''', shell=True)
```

Comment: @dmorgan seems block formatting doesn't work here. So check here https://pastebin.com/agXNFjaU

Comment: Thanks. Ya I did try that too.  Added a  '\' in each of the lines and still I don't see any changes in the output.

Comment: @dmorgan silly question - have you tried to wrap it with print: `print(check_output(...).decode('utf8'))`?

Comment: Ya I tried. But I'm getting a 'File not found error'  error now , But I do have the file. I get a 'File not  found 'for each of the commands in the specified find statement

Comment: @dmorgan Maybe try to test your code step by step - try simple find, then try to replace the loop with simple `ls`, etc.

Comment: Ya thanks will try out